# Hyperlinking .mpg files to cells in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a couple of rows of some strings and I'd like to assign them to mpg movies. For example "`101 Home Visit 33`" need to be linked with `101asd.mpg`, the first 3 characters are the same every time. In one catalogue there are over 50 mpg files so I had an idea to make a macro which by using **ctrl+h**  does it automatically (I mean searching and hyper linking). I don't know how to search for a file name. To make it easier I've created second column just with first three characters (101) and its called file_number My code:

```
Sub Makro1()
'Dim i As Integer
Dim cell_name As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim file_number As String

ActiveCell.Select
cell_name = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Select

file_number = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Select

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    file_number & "*.mpeg", TextToDisplay:= _
    file_name


End Sub
```

Something is wrong with this part:

```
file_number & "*.mpeg", TextToDisplay:= _
    file_name
```

or to be more precise

```
"*.mpeg"
```

because I'm trying to cover some characters with *.

What is wrong?

Comment: To concatenate values in VB you want to use &. So for the Address:= you want it to be: file_number & ".mpeg" also, you have the TextToDisplay as file_name, but you are storing the value as cell_name above.

Comment: you're right. I forgot to do this. Still macro works but the .mpg file cannot open

Comment: You will need the entire path to the file listed in the Address, right now it will try to open C:\file_number.mpeg, you will want to put in the whole path. Something like "C:\MyFile\" & file_number & ".mpeg" (make sure the file extension matches as well).

Comment: the excel file and mpeg files are always in one catalogue so i'd like to avoid wrting whole path

Comment: So now the only problem is that how to replace some symbols in file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the other things discussed, you can store the workbook path as a variable to reference if they are all in the same file:

```
Sub Makro1()
'All Your Other Stuff

Dim strPath As String

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    strPath & "\" & file_number & ".mpeg", TextToDisplay:= _
    file_name
'TextToDisplay may be cell_name depending on how you adjusted your code.

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this but now i know the problem is that there is *.mpg and i thought that * can replace some characters now i noticed i cannot. file name is 101asd.mpg

Comment: And sometimes file name is 230wee.mpeg

Comment: The * wildcard has to be used in specific ways, in this case it has no way of determining how you want that to be filled. I would look into the [Dir()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php) function to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't understad why. strPath & "\" & file_number & ".*mpeg" should give me file which name is "file_numberasd.mpg" and * should replace "asd", am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved without using *. I tried in different ways but none of them worked.

```
Sub Makro1()

For Each cell In Selection

If cell.Value = "" Then

Else
Call linkowanie
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select 'Jump to lower cell
Next cell


End Sub

Sub linkowanie()

Dim cell_name As String
Dim file_number As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim file_names() As String 'Dynamic array for file names

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Path shows way to excel file

ActiveCell.Select
cell_name = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Select

file_number = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Select

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Create an       instance of the FileSystemObject

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath) 'Get the folder object

 i = 0

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
ReDim Preserve file_names(i)
file_names(i) = objFile.Name
i = i + 1
Next objFile

For k = 0 To i - 1
If Mid(file_names(k), 1, 6) = file_number Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    strPath & "\" & file_names(k), TextToDisplay:= _
    cell_name
End If
Next k


End Sub
```